# Can I use "there" twice in the same sentence?

Tags: word-usage, existentials

There is many food there.

> There <strike>*is*</strike> *are* many <strike>*food*</strike> *foods* there.

Is the above sentence correct ?

Comment: No, your example is not correct. But it's nothing to do with using the word ***there*** twice. You've got the "plurality" of the verb and noun wrong - it should be *There **are** many **foods** there*. In which context ***foods*** is "countable" - many different ***types of** food*, as opposed to "uncountable" *There is **much** food there* (a ***lot** of food*).

Comment: It's okay now that it has been edited. "There" has two distinct functions in your example. The first "there" is a dummy pronoun as subject, the second an adverb (or preposition) as locative complement.

Comment: You can even use there more than twice, as in Gertrude Stein's classic "there's no there there".

Comment: Maybe even more confusing: "There is a lot of food here" would also be valid, in spiteof the apparent conflict between *there* and *here*

Comment: There is nothing there !

Comment: There, there, it's OK.  Just watch out trying to use "many" for a mass (uncountable) noun.

Answer (score 25):

Your use of 'there' twice is fine. However, your use of 'many' is wrong, as 'food' is singular. In most contexts, you could use 'much' instead. That would be gramatical here:

> There is much food there.

but that doesn't sound great to a native English speaker - instead, simply

> There is a lot of food there.

Use 'many' for plural nouns e.g.

> There are many pizzas there.

Comment: You are probably right to presume that the OP means "a lot of food," but "there are many foods there" (as the question was edited to read) would usually mean "many different types of food." "Many pizzas" doesn't imply many variations of pizza, but "many foods" does. Probably worth pointing that out so that the OP gets the proper advice?

Comment: _"that doesn't sound great to a native English speaker"_ I'm English and it sounds great! A little over-styled perhaps but, depending on company, that could be a good thing.

Comment: "There is _so_ much food there!", on the other hand, seems quite standard to my untrained ear.

Answer (score 8):

There **are** many foods there. Food in this use is plural so you need *are* instead of *is*. Using the word *there* twice in this example is fine and perfectly common and understandable.

Comment: Also, while "There are many foods there" may technically be correct, it sounds very stilted. Food in plural form is uncommon. A native speaker would be more likely to say something similar to "There is a lot of food there" or "There are many different kinds of food there", depending on the exact intended meaning of the sentence, to avoid pluralizing food.

Comment: @Aiaimai  I agree that I would not necessarily say it like that, but it does depend on where you are from. Some places are more casual than others. I tend to answer the exact question and forget that the OP may want the more colloquial answer.

Comment: If I heard "There are many foods there" from a native speaker, I'd think they were talking about variety. If I knew they were a non-native speaker, I'd think it was an error.

Comment: @TecBrat  and that is exactly what I assumed. If OP does not mean 'variety' -- that's different.

Answer (score 5):

The word *there* can have multiple uses or meanings.

[There is/are] is a way to express *existence*.

[there] can also express *location*.

These sentences use both meanings, and there's nothing wrong with that.

> Many foods [exist] [in that location].

Answer (score 1):

'There, there' is in itself a phrase used to comfort someone;
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There,+there

It's also a brilliant Radiohead song;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AQSLozK7aA